# Datepicker not showing up in the required_date field

Tags: jquery, django, datepicker

Unable to show datepicker in the required_date field. Following are the models, the forms.

Models:

```
class Request(BaseTimeModel):
    required_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=DETAIL_FIELD, blank=True, null=True)


class PurchaseRequest(Request):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, blank=False, null=False, related_name="vendor_purchase_requests")
    status = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseRequestStatus, null=True, blank=True)
```

Forms:

```
class PurchaseRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseRequest
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "required_date": forms.DateInput(attrs={"class": "datepicker"}),
        }
```

And the view is :

```
class PurchaseRequestCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PurchaseRequest

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form = PurchaseRequestForm()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,                           
                                  ))
```

In the template, class datepicker has been added.

```
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Update:

```
{% extends "inventory/base.html" %}
{% block legend %} Create Purchase Request {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
   <form id="myForm" method="post" action="" class="col-sm-12">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            {{ form }}
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            {% block action_buttons %}
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="submit btn btn-success btn-sm" name="save_request"/>
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show your template?